# How to force maven repository indexing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, geotools

I have `m2e` installed in `Eclipse` and global maven configured in it. Recently I have added two geottools repositories, but `Eclipse` does not show them:

[image]

Also it is not finding artefacts from it, like `gt-shapefile`.

How to force indexing? `Rebuild Index` and `Update Index` did not help. Removing `m2e` plugin folders from `.metadata` workspace folder also didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Preferences* > *Maven*
and select 
**Download repository index updates on startup** check box

Restarting eclipse should trigger index download for each repository. Also note that Repository should provide an index in first place for this option to work.

Please see error log ( *Window* > *Show View* ) for any related messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if I don't want to do it every time I start Eclipse?

Comment: @BrianTopping ... then disable it after enabling and sync ... see next comment for details

Comment: "*Download repository index updates on startup*" actually means "***Enable repository index updates (additionally on startup)***" ... see 2. point here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897567/1915920

Comment: @BrianTopping in other words ... restarting eclipse is not necessary (tested e.g. with eclipse 4.17 2021-09)

Comment: @AndreasCovidiot Comment is from 2015...