# How to configure a proxy server for both HTTP and HTTPS in Maven's settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven, http, https, proxy

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 behind a proxy server. The same proxy handles both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` traffic.

I can't seem to tell maven using `settings.xml` to use both protocols. It seems to me that it is only possible to have one active proxy, as whichever active proxy is defined first is used, and subsequent 'active' proxy definitions are ignored. This is my `settings.xml`:

```xml
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>myhttpproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>192.168.1.2</host>
        <port>3128</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
        <id>myhttpsproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <host>192.168.1.2</host>
        <port>3128</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Is it possible to configure a proxy for both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` in maven's `settings.xml`?  I'm aware that I could workaround this by passing Java system properties to the maven invocation such as:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.1.2 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

but surely this must be possible from within `settings.xml`?

Maven bugs raised such as [MNG-2305](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2305) and [MNG-4394](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4394) suggest this issue is resolved, but I am not convinced.

Alternatively, is there a "proxy proxy" I could run locally that I could point maven to?  The "proxy proxy" would route http/https accordingly.  Even so, I would still need to define two active proxy definitions in `settings.xml` for Maven to direct both types of traffic.

Answer (score 56):

Maven proxy from settings.xml is used for both http and https, so you just need to define one proxy server and it will be used for both, you just need to leave only one `proxy` tag, like this:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>myhttpproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>192.168.1.2</host>
        <port>3128</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

The protocol above is the protocol of the proxy server, not the proxied request.

Comment: Very useful information, a shame you were not credited more for it. +1, worked for me.

Comment: @krzyk [maven's settings documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) would seem to agree with you:
_protocol, host, port: The protocol://host:port of the proxy, separated into discrete elements._
I will attempt to re-test this - it has been some time now...!

Comment: I know this looks like the protocol refers to the proxy's protocol, but for me it did not work with only one proxy. When I have added two proxies, like the OP suggested, then for me it worked (with Maven 3.3.9). At first it didn't work because I copy/pasted the proxy server in settings.xml and I forgot to put a different id for the second proxy server. After I put a different id, it worked.

Comment: @StephenHartley Have you had a chance to test it out?

Comment: Does not work. You need to proxy entries, one for HTTP, one for HTTPS, _but_ you must use the ID tags, with different IDs, else the one will be ignored

Comment: I posted my answer of real world tests using Eclipse Maven that showed that `protocol` is indeed for the proxy server and not the url request, and that maven only uses the first active proxy and ignores any others.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508940 . @SorinPostelnicu @StephenHartley @MaxRobbertze

Answer (score 3):

Update 2022-01: a more up-to-date answer/solution for the current tech-stack (Eclipse 4.17 / 2020-09) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897567/1915920)
(old: 4.6 / 2017)

It **works without** the extra **`...<id>httpsproxy</id>...` entry** (as @Krzysztof Krasoń mentioned) and with it (as the asker stated).
The problem for us was, that the <s>`Eclipse->Maven->User Settings->[x] Update Settings`</s> was obviously not working at all and to test certain things `Eclipse->Maven->[x] Download repository index updates on startup` must be checked (e.g. `Maven Repositories View->Global Repositories->central->Update Index`). And most of all:

**Eclipse must be restarted after every `settings.xml` update! :-/**

I guess it's a bug or reload/caching issue.
We successfully tested it with

- Kepler (4.3) and Neon (4.6)
- and their embedded Maven versions (3.2.1 / 3.3.9) as well as an external
  3.3.3
- with `http://` and `https://` URLs

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with updating the maven version, or in other words not using the embedded eclipse maven version, but external version 3.3.9.

Answer (score 2):

My tests with Eclipse Maven show that the `protocol` in `settings.xml` is referring to the protocol of the **proxy server**, not the protocol of the **URL request**. It also shows that Maven only uses the first active proxy server listed, and ignores the rest.

Here's my evidence:

**1. The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) says that**

> **active**: true if this proxy is active. This is useful for declaring a set of proxies, but only one may be active at a time.
>
> **protocol**, host, port: The **protocol://host:port of the proxy**, separated into discrete elements."

**2. The [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a2b800de32cdb9adc1e64a43a0fc32e3ba878103/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/repository/Proxy.java) is even clearer:**

```
    /**
     * Get the protocol of the proxy server.
     * @return the protocol of the proxy server
     */
    public String getProtocol()
    {
        return protocol;
    }
```

**3. Real world tests (using Eclipse Maven):**

**a. 1st proxy is a bogus ftp, 2nd is real http, 3rd is real https. Result: FAIL.**

If the protocol were for the URL request, then Maven would've looked up the real http/https proxies and worked perfectly fine. Instead, it used the 1st proxy even though it was "ftp", and failed.

```
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>bogus_ftp</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>ftp</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>bogus.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>real_http</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>real.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>real_https</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>real.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
```

**b. 1st proxy is real http, 2nd is bogus https. Result: SUCCESS.**

This shows that it only used the 1st proxy. Otherwise, it would have used the 2nd proxy for https requests, hit the bogus proxy server, and failed.

```
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>real_http</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>real.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>bogus_https</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>bogus.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
```

**c. Both are http, but 1st proxy is bogus, 2nd is real. Result: FAIL.**

This shows that maven doesn't use multiple proxies, even for the same protocol. Otherwise, it would have tried the 2nd real proxy and succeeded.

```
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>bogus_http</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>bogus.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>real_http</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <port>123</port>
            <host>real.proxy.com</host>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
```

Comment: Dear @wisbucky, in all your 3 tests you forgot to specify different ids for the proxy declarations. If you specify different ids then it works. Probably the problem is that Maven generates a default id when missing, and it generates the same id for all the proxy declarations. Could you please try again all your examples but with valid distinct ids, and tell us if it's indeed working with more than one active proxy?

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu, That's a good point. I re-tested all 3 examples with distinct `<id>`s (I edited the post to reflect this). Exact same results as before. You can probably take advantage of the `id`s with command line arguments, but Eclipse Maven does not by default.

Comment: It works when running mvn from the command line, but indeed I did not test with Eclipse Maven. If it does not work, then it should be filed as a bug for Elipse Maven.

Answer (score 2):

For ***Eclipse** 4.17 (2020-09)* with *M2E 1.16.1* (**and the focus it should especially work there!**) and *Maven 3.3.3 (external) or 3.6.3 (embedded)* (and likely similar combinations/versions) it works for **mixed `http://...` and `https://...` repo URLs** with the following setup (other than in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781054/1915920)):

e.g. to make it work for `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`:

- `<url> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 </url>`
- `<url> http://my-local-repo/repository/rep1 </url>`
- `<url> http://my-local-sonatype-nexus-repo-manager-oss-v3/repository/rep2 </url>`

you need:

1. **two entries** in your `<usr-home>/.m2/settings.xml` if some repos have `http://` and some `https://` URLs (unfortunately not like maybe stated in docs or in older Maven or m2e versions/combinations)

   ```
    <proxy>
        <id>http</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <port>8080</port>
        <host>some-proxy.com</host>
    </proxy>

    <proxy>
        <id>https</id>  <!-- important!: different id than above! -->
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <port>8080</port>
        <host>some-proxy.com</host>
    </proxy>
   ```
2. additionally the Eclipse **M2E plugin has the problem to not sync at all if** the
   *Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> **[x] Download repository index updates on startup*** is **not enabled**
   (=> thus one could **think of it as: "*[x] Enable repository index updates (additionally on startup)*"**)
3. furthermore **some repos**, e.g. the known Sonatype's *Nexus Repository Manager* v3 (at least 3.2), **do not support indexing out-of-the-box** (do not get confused by [feature request NEXUS-17279](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-17279)) and thus one has at least two options:

   - **set up index generation jobs for desired/unindexed repos**
     (`Repo Admin UI -> Config -> Tasks -> Create Task ->` [`Maven - Publish Maven Indexer files`](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/tasks#Tasks-Maven-PublishMavenIndexerfiles) ...)

     - in M2E: `Minimum Index Enabled` should suffice (may take 20 min to index for central)
   - **disable indexing for such repos** in the *Maven Repository* view (Eclipse workspace wide)

     - right click those repos and select ***Index Details Disabled***
       (should become grayed out)
   - to **check if some repo supports indexing** (whether by config or design) you could check if the file **`<repo-base-url>/repX/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties` exists**

     - e.g. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
   - a [list of free/commercial repo managers](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) is provided on the Apache Maven Project website, where those open source ones support it (last checked 2022-02-10):

     - [Apache Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.7/adminguide/repositories.html)
     - [JFrog Artifactory Open Source](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Indexer)
     - [Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467162/how-to-download-remote-index-in-nexus-oss-3-2/41470500#41470500)
4. to be sure to not run into caching or crash problems you should **restart Eclipse (e.g. with `-clean` option)** in case something does not work right away after the above setup
5. Do not get confused: we experienced that the **servers UI search (Nexus Manager) did not always display all available matches** (but the M2E client did), e.g. `"groovy-all"` did only return some `2.*` versions whereas some `3.*` were in fact also available.

   - (*Task jobs* to repair the browse/search indizes did not help it)

Of course without indexing one would loose the ability to search within repo artifacts but the **direct download should always work** nevertheless.

- e.g. via *`pom.xml` -> right click -> Maven -> Add Dependency -> Enter groupId, artifactId ...*

  - if you enter `groovy` in this generic search field there should be quite some suggestions if it works, "*artifactId cannot be empty*" or "*groupId cannot be empty*" warnings can be ignored (and any content in both will be ignored then):
    [image]

    - if it still does not work, maybe *Window -> Show view -> Maven Repositories ->  -> `Full Index Enabled`* must be checked (may take a while to complete)
      (Eclipse restart not necessary)