# Proxies in Maven's settings.xml

Tags: proxy, maven-3

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31032174/483113) I'm trying to get my setup to work, but the tests keep failing as they can't connect to the remote site. I upgraded to Maven 3.3.9.

This is my `settings.xml` that I want to get working:

```
<settings>

  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>httpProxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.local</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.local</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>httpsProxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>10.20.20.208</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.local</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
:
```

This is a small part, which already doesn't work:

```
<settings>

  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>10.20.20.208</host>
      <port>3128</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
:
```

I also tried to put IP-addresses in there.

I know that Maven picks that XML, because Maven says so in its debug messages and if I break the syntax of it Maven complains.

The only thing that really works is passing `-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.local -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128` to Maven.

What is it that I'm doing wrong in my XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are likely not going to read the `settings.xml` as that's for Maven as that's for the Maven build and their plugins.

You can double check this by adding in `-X` and see what properties are sent to your tests when surefire is running.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the checked answer I tried to make it all work and actually only had to fix the plug-in configuration of `maven-failsafe-plugin`:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- added -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort -->
          <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.local -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128</argLine>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*ITest.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

So I leave this here in case anyone stumbles across the same misunderstanding...