# Error:Cannot find class in classpath: testCases.MyClassName & errors in class after deleting .m2

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I am working on Selenium testNg framework, and I get this error:

```
Cannot find class in classpath: testCases.MyClassName.
```

I am facing this error after I pulled the updated code from `git` and made changes to the code in my local but did not commit it and trying to perform unit testing in my local. I did project clean, maven clean and install. Updated the project and tried running the code again and received same error message. I checked the classname & package name in `testing.xml` and they are correct, as suggested by my friend to delete `.m2` repository, restart eclipse and pull the code. I deleted `.m2` repository, restarted and saw errors in all the test cases in the package, and could not pull the code. 
Could you please suggest on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am afraid ... how is your question connected to `Selenium`?

Comment: I am just giving the information on what i am doing

Comment: Any idea what is the issue ??

Comment: @sravya Remove testng dependency, and Run Maven Test. And now add testng dependency and Run Maven Test.

Comment: @sravya - You have either a corrupted eclipse workspace (or) your eclipse settings that reside in your project directory are corrupted (`.settings`, `.classpath`, `.project`). So first remove the project from your eclipse workspace (dont delete the files, but just remove it), run `mvn eclipse:clean` from command line, re-import the project back into eclipse and see if that helps.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I tried doing what you said- it helped me to get out of error but I have a below error in pom.xml

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan-I did what you told but there is one error in pom.xml-Failure to transfer com.github.klieber:phantomjs-maven-plugin:pom:0.7 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached 
 in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.github.klieber:phantomjs-maven-plugin:pom:0.7 from/to central (https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy                        
  Maven clean-success, but maven build-failed

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan- I have removed the project from eclipse workspace but could not reimport them. Proxy settings are fine now, I re-imported the cloned project and did maven clean and maven install. I have a below error in maven install

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project ProjectName: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Comment: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:pom:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs when you have corrupted your eclipse workspace or your eclipse settings that reside in your project ( `.settings`, `.classpath`, `.project`).

You can try doing the following

- Remove the project from your eclipse workspace (dont delete the files, but just remove them)
- Run `mvn eclipse:clean` from the command prompt (This will remove all the eclipse files)
- Re-import the project into eclipse

For the additional error you are facing, looks like you a proxy issue.

You can try creating a `settings.xml` in your `~/.m2` folder with end-points as `http` instead of `https` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781054) or you can try including your credentials to be used against your proxy server (seems like you are having one) as described [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/)

(Quoting the relevant sections from the link) basically you need to add a section as below into your `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```xml
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>mkyong</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <host>proxy.mkyong.com</host>
        <port>8888</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```