# maven versions plugin does not respect proxy settings

Tags: maven, proxy

I am attempting to update my dependencies via the maven versions plugin and am unable to do so since it is not going through my proxy.

```
mvn versions:update-properties
```

My firewall log shows it is dropping connections on port 443 as it is attempting to go directly to the Internet; however, I have a proxy specified in my ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
        <proxies>
                <proxy>
                        <host>${HOSTNAME_GOES_HERE}</host>
                        <port>${PORT_GOES_HERE}</port>
                        <active>true</active>
                </proxy>
        </proxies>
```

Is there a way to make it work without changing my firewall rules?

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Did you solve it? Same problem here...

Comment: I ultimately stopped using a proxy server since very little traffic was going through it and I didn't want to do SSL snooping.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `versions-maven-plugin` uses the protocol tag in the proxy settings wrong. After I changed the protocol tag to `https`, the `versions-maven-plugin` used my proxy server as intended:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
        <proxies>
                <proxy>
                        <host>${HOSTNAME_GOES_HERE}</host>
                        <port>${PORT_GOES_HERE}</port>
                        <protocol>https</protocol>
                        <active>true</active>
                </proxy>
        </proxies>
</settings>
```

This does go in line with the following Github Issue: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/421

However, this does not reflect the usage as intended by Maven. This answer shows that the protocol tag is intended for the protocol of the `proxy-server` and not the `target-url`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508940/5945416

Maven worked perfectly fine for me with the protocol tag set to https instead of http and the versions plugin had problems as soon as I switched back to http, therefore I will leave it at that.

Tested on:

- Maven: 3.8.1
- versions-maven-plugin: 2.8.1