# Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to build a `spring-boot` maven project from a jenkins pipeline.

**Error**:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for xxx.xxxxx.xxxx:finance-portal:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
 Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.2 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.2 
 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
 Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.24.215] failed: 
 Connection refused (Connection refused) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 10
```

**maven goal**:

```
clean install -U -X
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**The resolutions I tried so far**:

1. Setting up org proxy through `settings.xml` file in jenkins and use the config in the pipeline.
2. Setting up proxies through maven goal: `clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=proxy.com -DproxyPort=xxxxx`.
3. Omitting/Changing `relativePath` tag in pom.xml to `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` and few other variants.
4. Remove jenkins workspace for the project and re-build it.
5. make a `curl` request to maven central repo before the build to check connection establishment: `curl -I -x proxy.com:xxxxx "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"`. The connection gets established but fails in the build process.

Comment: This is the wrong location: `repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.24.215` which means you have change some configurations ...or you have an issue with a proxy/firewall...

Comment: @khmarbaise which is the correct one btw? any idea how to change? proxy is fine bcoz curl works with the proxy.

Comment: @khmarbaise any lead pls

Comment: Why do you have relativePath at all? Omit the line, per [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.first-application.pom). Also, our Central is defined as https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. No issues whatsoever. Check with `mvn help:effective-settings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `30thh`'s answer was definitely helpful for troubleshooting, as a last resort I just cloned a working VM to a new instance, created my pipeline there and it worked like a charm in the first attempt. So it's pretty evident that it was something to do with `proxy/firewall` of the previous VM/jenkins.

Answer (score 4):

I bet you missed something configuring the proxy setting. For example set up the wrong protocol or you misspelled/misplaced the `proxies` tag in the `setting.xml` file.

Here is an example from Apache manual:

```
<settings>
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
</settings>
```

The protocol seems to be a protocol of the proxy server, not of the proxied request. Here is a long discussion about this point:

[How to configure a proxy server for both HTTP and HTTPS in Maven's settings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032174/how-to-configure-a-proxy-server-for-both-http-and-https-in-mavens-settings-xml)

It is also possible your `setting.xml` was placed on the wrong place. Here is the default location:

```
(Linux) /home/bob/.m2/settings.xml
(Windows) C:\Users\bob\.m2\settings.xml
```

IDE or CD/CI pipeline could override the default location. It can be done like this:

```
mvn --settings your_location/settings.xml clean install
(or) 
mvn -s your_location/settings.xml clean install
```

Another problem could be the conflict with JVM proxy configuration. I am not sure, which configuration has priority. JVM uses its own arguments:

```
http.proxyHost (default: <none>) 
http.nonProxyHosts (default: localhost|127.*|[::1])
http.proxyPort (default: 80)
https.proxyHost(default: <none>)
https.proxyPort (default: 443)
```

Here `http` and `https` are protocols of the proxied request (at least AFAIU)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

One more possible problem could be the argument `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies`. If it is set to `true` (default - `false`) the operation system wide proxy configuration is used.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. it was definitely something related to proxy/firewall in this particular VM i was trying to deploy. I cloned a working VM to a new instance, created the pipeline and bingo it worked like a charm.